# C .pc file warning

Tags: c, warnings

This is my warning.

```
warning : implicit  declaration of function 'sqlglm'
```

The warning comes in a bi.pc file.

when i check the bi.c file.

it doesn't include

```
#include <sqlcpr.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
```

As .c file generate at compile time.
there is no need to edit .c file

i am using linux & gcc compiler,C.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion I made when you asked this question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408898/c-pc-file-warning/2409150#2409150

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but to be helpful to people who might stumble on it via search engine like me, the **right** answer is:

you have to add the following lines to your Pro*C source

```
EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca.h;
EXEC SQL INCLUDE oraca.h;
EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlcpr.h;
```

The `sqlca.h` and `oraca.h` are required before `sqlcpr.h` can be included. A standard C header like `stddef.h` or `stdio.h` have to be included before these embedded SQL statements as they need to have `size_t` defined.

It is important to use the embedded SQL include statements instead of the C `#include`.
The `EXEC SQL INCLUDE` will copy the content of the header file into the generated C file. Therefore, it is not necessary to add the other include file paths of the Oracle client into the C compiler command line.

Answer (score 1):

`warning : implicit  declaration of function 'sqlglm'` shows up when function has been defined in some other header file, but has not been `#include`d, or the function has not been defined at all. So, include the file which defines it or define it yourself.

---

Update
Use `#include "sqlcpr.h"` *(in case `sqlcpr.h` is not in compiler's search paths and is in the same directory as the source file)*

Comment: i tried to include 

#include <sqlcpr.h>

in my .pc file.

it shows compilation error.

Comment: there is no internet access in that machine.

but the compilation stops

& shows error1.

Comment: @ambika If you want to get some assistance you need to put some effort yourself. You can always write error message down and type it for SO